# Reliability of the Activity Lifecycle (onPause to onDestory)

Tags: android, lifecycle

After years of trusting the lifecycle, i did a little digging.
Now i am not amused.

I know and read a lot about that `onStop` is not guaranteed to be called etc.

I created a simple App with 2 Activites and a custom Application class. I put a Log.d() in every callback that i could find and played around on a Galaxy S2 with 4.1 on it.
Activity A launches on start and in its `onResume` it starts Activity B. Activity B has a Button that creates a Nullpointer but otherwise it is doing nothing.

Now the things that worry/confuse me:

- if i create a nullpointer on buttonclick, the app crashes and NO callback happens in neither activity
- if i hit the powerbutton and turn off the screen, the activity will be restarted if the display mode (portrait or landscape) of the activity doesnt match the native orientation of the device. I do know that and how i could override it but IF it destroys and restarts my activity it calls `onPause` and `isFinishing()` returns false but the activity is being finished and restarted.
- if above does not happen, only `onPause` is being called even though the app is no longer visible
- starting another activity calls `onPause` in A, then creates B to `onResume` and then calls `onStop` of A. Now i am tracking my activites in the .App class and if i unregister A in `onPause` and register B in `onResume`, there will be a split millisecond where no activity is registered. If i wanted to shut down some service when no activity is there, it would happen all the time. But if i unregister it in `onStop` (so they would overlap) it would never be unregistered when the user hits the powerbutton and the service (or thread or whatever) keeps running and draining battery power.

I am working with android for quite some time now and i am trying to achieve a rather complex or lets say bulletproof design. But its almost impossible to keep track of what is happening to my activities.

- powerdown has to be detected via Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF but that happens when its already off. The only thing before that would be onPause.
- homebutton... some combination of onUserInteraction and pause/stop

Its really hard to simply determine when my APP (not just one activity) is no longer being used and put in the background and when its just transitioning between activites or when its being shut down by the system. Because the .App class has NO callback for termination as `onTerminate()` is only used in emulator, so the docs say.

Maybe im just not seeing the forest through the trees...
help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious about why do you care about this. As long as an activity is paused, you should release resources. I'd do pretty much everything in `onPause`.

Comment: because not everything can be picked up/started again in milliseconds and pause can simply mean transition to another activity

Comment: What are you trying to do with ms accuracy? Could you elaborate on this in your question with perhaps an example? Anyway, IMHO, you should keep the design simple and use `onPause/onResume` no matter what triggers it (device rotation, any other config change, device going to sleep, user pressing buttons, etc etc). Think about all the difficulties you are having with your current approach: is detecting the whole casuistry really neccesary? Could you do the same thing using a different simpler approach?

Comment: best example would be the connection to a server (like in a game). If you disconnect in every onPause and reconnect in the next onResume, you would be dis/con everytime you switch an activity. Without fragments this is very common in bigger apps.

Answer (score 3):

The Android lifecycle can be pretty confusing, and so far I've found only one way that lets you have a decent idea of what's going on around you.

You design your app in a way that you're always assuming you can be killed at any instant without callbacks like `onDestroy()` being called, because there is no guarantee that they will be called at all.

A simple way to check whether an Activity is going into the background because another one of your Activities is coming to the front is by using a simple flag:

```
boolean movingInApp = false;
....
movingInApp = true;
Intent intent...
.....
public void onPause() {
    if(movingInApp) {
        //Called because we're moving to another Activity in our own app
    }
}

public void onResume() {
    movingInApp = false;

}
```

By setting the value of `movingInApp` to `true` before launching any intent etc, you can keep track of why `onPause()` is being called. Remember to set it to `false` again later in your `onResume()` method. If the system makes your app go to the background, this will be false, and you know that your app was moved to the background by someone else, and not you.

As for nothing being called when an exception occurs, Android simply kills your entire App process whenever there is an uncaught exception. Your app simply stops running, like when you force quit a program on your computer. The system kills is completely and without any warning. No more code is executed at all.

Comment: I wander what happens if I did not release something in native code and my app being killed like that.

Comment: @DoctororDrive I've not really worked with the NDK, so I'm not sure, but my guess is that everything you're doing, either from native code or Java, will stop completely. All resources used by your app will be released, and any unfinished file IO will stop as is.

Comment: @MisterSmith I don't think that will be a problem here. There is only one UI thread, and I don't see why you would access that flag from a background thread.

Comment: @RaghavSood yes, it's very likely, but I want to be sure.

Comment: sorry for not accepting this answer but i feel it only answers a small part of the problem

Comment: @NikkyD No problem. There's no obligation to accept if you feel it doesn't solve your problem :)